# How to get std output from program

Tags: macos, stdout

This is a bit hard for me to put in words, but I will try my best.
When you run a program from Terminal (im on OS X), you can see all output, for example from printf() calls. But if I execute something without a terminal (e.g. with double clicking) that makes debugging output with printf(), how can I see this output?

I believe it has something to do with debuggers and attaching processes to them (?) , but I have never really understood those things...

Sorry for the weird description, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Just trying to understand... but, why not just run it in the Terminal so you can see debug statements?

Comment: @Mark Setchell to be specific I am trying to develop an audio unit plugin. It runs and everything works but those plugins are executed by the host program. I can't execute them standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Using NSLog(), all output was visible in the Apple Console application.